# how to compile single LESS file in magento2

Tags: magento2, compiler, less

I am working on magento2 theming part. Here we have some predefined and my custom LESS file. Whenever we compile LESS file, it generates two css file -- styles-l.css, styles-m.css . But we do not know from which LESS file, my css is going to styles-l.css and styles-m.css. Is there any way to find out this issue? I want to see from which file (line number too) my code is coming ? Is there any way to solve these issues ? Any help is  really appreciated. Currently i am doing deploy static data. It compiles all LESS files. I want to compile single LESS file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the Grunt for your server, check below url to setup the Grunt .

http://ericnish.io/blog/compile-less-files-with-grunt/

Inside the Gruntfile.js you can add the code like below example

**For single File compile us the following code**

```
files: {
          "css/main.css": "less/main.less" // destination file and source file
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile only 1 file makes no sense.

But you can use SourceMap for your compiled CSS to see in which line & file is your sourcecode.

Enable SourceMap-Support in Chrome Browser:

http://dannycroft.co.uk/enabling-source-maps-in-chrome/